# SSRS for SharePoint - Configuration Issues

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, reporting-services

My team has installed SSRS in SharePoint mode with the add-in successfully. I'm seeing it as an active service on my SharePoint instance without any issues. It seems to be working fine server-side. However, when I go to the site collection to activate the features, I'm not seeing it there. Nor am I seeing it as a content type. Help?

SSRS Installation: 2016

SharePoint Server Enterprise 2016

SharePoint Mode installation complete

SharePoint add-in complete

Service is started and running

Service is active on the web application

Answer (score 0):

You may check whether the features like "**Report Server Integration Feature**" (Identity:89ec7-70fd-4179-a1c4-6fcb4342d7a0) and "**Reporting**" (Identity:4bd89-2cfe-490a-8c7e-fbace37b4a34) are installed and available in the Farm by using PS, [found here](https://johanleino.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/using-powershell-to-list-all-features-with-title-and-id/).

```
Get-SPFeature | Sort @{Expression={$_.GetTitle(1033)}} -Descending:$false | ft @{Label='ID';Width=40;Expression={$_.Id}}, @{Label='Title';Width=250;Expression={$_.GetTitle(1033)}} | Out-File -Width 350 "c:\TEMP\features.txt"
```

Also, is the service online? You may check using PS.

```
$SSRSServers = @("MyServerOne", "MyServerTwo")


$SSRSServers | foreach-object {
        $serverName = $_
        $ssrsI = get-spserviceinstance | where {$_.server -like "*" + $serverName -and $_.TypeName -like "SQL Server Reporting*"} 
        Write-Host "Server=" $serverName  "Service Name=" $ssrsI.TypeName  "status=" $ssrsI.Status
  }
```

Once those features are activated, you need to create a Library using "Report Library" and then add the Content Types like *Report Builder Model*, *Report Builder Report*, and *Report Data Source*

Comment: Hi Matiur. Thanks for your response. I did notice that  I am seeing the service running under CA, I am not seeing it under the service management console. I assume this is where my problem lies?

Comment: Just to clarify - your are seeing "SQL Server Reporting Services Service" in started status on "Services on Server" screen in CA, but not seeing on the "Manage Service Applications" screen, right? Have you created the Reporting Service application and proxy? PS cmds are:New-SPRSServiceApplication and New-SPRSServiceApplicationProxy

Comment: Hi, Matiur. I am seeing it as a started service on both. I am not seeing it as a feature that is able to be activated on my site collections. I did some installation checkers, and it seems to be installed correctly. But my assumption is the feature would be able to be activated if it was. I am considering rolling back the installation and doing it again.

Comment: Once you recreate the SSRS Service Application, make sure your Web Application has "Service Connections" to the SSRS Service Application Proxy by visiting Manage Web Applications=> Service Connections

Comment: Hi Matiur, it does. I did verify this already :(. Thank you.